# How to update y values with sliders in plotly (python)

Tags: python, plotly

I have a simplified `Sliders` example from `Plotly` in **python**.

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
tmp = [1, 2]
data = [dict(
    x=tmp,
    y=tmp,
    mode='lines'
)]

sliders = [dict(
    steps=[dict(
        label=i,
        args=['mode', i]
    ) for i in ['lines', 'markers']])
]
layout = dict(sliders=sliders)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig, filename='SimpleSlider.html')
```

It restyles `mode` part of layout, switching berween `lines` and `markers` modes.

The question is how to switch between `'y'` values; say, between `tmp=[1,2]` and `[3, 4]`?

Is it possible or other libraries with `widgets` should be used?

Comment: try looking at the use of [callbacks](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2)

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak, thank you, your link points to `dash` libraries. So the answer is 'no' when it comes to 'pure' plotly realization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 'pure' plotly please consult [this thread](https://community.plot.ly/t/click-events-in-python-offline-mode/298): the answer is basically *'no, but you can try'* and points to using `Dash` as easier solution.

Comment: `plotly` makes a great progress and there is just one man behind all this - we could be thankful for what already achieved. But perhaps you can cross post or link this question to the community forum, for illustration of demand.